# How do I setup android test framework espresso as a maven project

Tags: java, maven, android-espresso

I have found example i.e. [Quality-Tools-for-Android](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/Quality-Tools-for-Android) repo which has [Maven with Espresso integration](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/Quality-Tools-for-Android#espresso) but this is outdated.

I want to integrated with https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.test.espresso/espresso-core but all the example available are integrated with gradle.

Found this example https://github.com/browserstack/espresso-browserstack and I tried it convert to maven. I am using Java 11.
Here is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample.browserstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>samplecalculator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    
    <repositories>
       <repository>
            <id>google</id>
            <url>https://maven.google.com</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.12.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.6.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Align the versions of conflicting dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>androidx.lifecycle</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-common</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Add other dependencies with version alignment if needed -->
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Android dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>androidx.appcompat</groupId>
            <artifactId>appcompat</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>androidx.constraintlayout</groupId>
            <artifactId>constraintlayout</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Android test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>androidx.test.espresso</groupId>
            <artifactId>espresso-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add other forced dependencies as needed -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>androidx.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>rules</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>androidx.test.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAXB dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I am getting below error when I am running **mvn clean install**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project samplecalculator: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sample.browserstack:samplecalculator:apk:1.0: 
The following artifacts could not be resolved: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:jar:1.0.0, androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:jar:1.1.3, androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:jar:3.1.0, androidx.test:runner:jar:1.1.0, androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:jar:3.1.0, androidx.test:rules:jar:1.1.1, androidx.test.ext:junit:jar:1.1.1, androidx.test:core:jar:1.2.0, androidx.test:monitor:jar:1.2.0: 
Failure to find androidx.appcompat:appcompat:jar:1.0.0 in https://nexus3.auiag.corp/repos/repository/iag-public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of swlibrary has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

What is missing in above pom.xml?

Need to understand if integration of espresso framework is not possible with maven?